# mongodb python get the element position from an array in a document

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I use python + mongodb to store some item ranking data in a collection called `chart`

```
{
  date: date1,
  region: region1,
  ranking: [
    {
      item: bson.dbref.DBRef(db.item.find_one()),
      price: current_price,
      version: '1.0'
    },
    {
      item: bson.dbref.DBRef(db.item.find_another_one()),
      price: current_price,
      version: '1.0'
    },
    .... (and the array goes on) 
  ]
}
```

Now my problem is, I want to make a history ranking chart for `itemA`. And according to [the `$` positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), the query should be something like this:

```
db.chart.find( {'ranking.item': bson.dbref.DBRef('item', itemA._id)}, ['$'])
```

And the `$` operator doesn't work.

Any other possible solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` positional operator is only used in `update(...)` calls, you can't use it to return the position within an array.

However, you can use [field projection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) to limit the fields returned to just those you need to calculate the position in the array from within Python:

```
db.foo.insert({
'date': '2011-04-01',
'region': 'NY',
'ranking': [
{ 'item': 'Coca-Cola', 'price': 1.00, 'version': 1 },
{ 'item': 'Diet Coke', 'price': 1.25, 'version': 1 },
{ 'item': 'Diet Pepsi', 'price': 1.50, 'version': 1 },
]})

db.foo.insert({
'date': '2011-05-01',
'region': 'NY',
'ranking': [
{ 'item': 'Diet Coke', 'price': 1.25, 'version': 1 },
{ 'item': 'Coca-Cola', 'price': 1.00, 'version': 1 },
{ 'item': 'Diet Pepsi', 'price': 1.50, 'version': 1 },
]})

db.foo.insert({
'date': '2011-06-01',
'region': 'NY',
'ranking': [
{ 'item': 'Coca-Cola', 'price': 1.00, 'version': 1 },
{ 'item': 'Diet Pepsi', 'price': 1.50, 'version': 1 },
{ 'item': 'Diet Coke', 'price': 1.25, 'version': 1 },
]})

def position_of(item, ranking):
    for i, candidate in enumerate(ranking):
            if candidate['item'] == item:
                    return i
    return None

print [position_of('Diet Coke', x['ranking'])
       for x in db.foo.find({'ranking.item': 'Diet Coke'}, ['ranking.item'])]

# prints [1, 0, 2]
```

In this (admittedly trivial) example, returning just a subset of fields may not show much benefit; however if your documents are especially large, doing may show performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks dcrosta. Your answer strike me with an idea: I can use MongoDB map-reduce to find the position in mongodb server directly :D